# Bash, double quotes and "reboot" command

Tags: bash

Assume you have those two statements in your bash script:

```
# No. 1
MSG="Automatic reboot now."
echo $MSG

# No. 2
MSG=""Automatic reboot now.""
echo $MSG
```

The output of statement number 1 is as expected (it is simply printed). If bash runs statement two, the machine is rebooted (any valid bash command will be executed).

But why?

Comment: Did you expect the second one to include literal quotes in the value of `MSG`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lesser known shell feature is the ability to set environment variables for the duration of a single command. This is done by prepending a command with one or more assignments, as in: `var1=foo var2=bar command`.

Here's a demonstration. Notice how the original value of `$MSG` is preserved.

```
$ export MSG=Hello
$ bash -c 'echo $MSG'
Hello
$ MSG=Goodbye bash -c 'echo $MSG'
Goodbye
$ bash -c 'echo $MSG'
Hello
```

Now on to your question:

```
MSG=""Automatic reboot now.""
```

The pairs of double quotes nullify each other, and might as well not be there. It's equivalent to:

```
MSG=Automatic reboot now.
```

which executes `reboot` with an argument of `now.` and the `$MSG` environment variable set to `Automatic`.

Answer (score 5):

That's because the meaning of `MSG=""Automatic reboot now.""` is the following:

> Execute `reboot now.` with the env. var. MSG set to `Automatic`.

It's equivalent to:

```
MSG=Automatic reboot now.
```